click() method from element object (HtmlUnit) is doing nothing
I am trying to crawl on this website: https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Apidog.shtml using html unit.
I want to "click" on "Download now" button, it should run js code and open a new windows over the page:
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.EDGE);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20 * 1000);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(patchUrl);
HtmlElement element = page.getFirstByXPath(xpath);
page = element.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);
return page.asXml();

I managed to get the html element by its xpath ("//*[@id="dlbtn1"]/a"), but calling to click() from it is doing nothing. Even if I call to sleep or to waitForBackgroundJavaScript() the readyState_ field in the HtmlElement is "loading" and not "completed".
Am I missing something? thanks.
Tried to change the code, serached for anawers here, looked into the documentation, nothing helped me.

Sites can implement anti-web scrapping measures to prevent such behaviour

When you open provided page for the first time, it shows a modal with Privacy notice and two buttons(try incognito mode if you do not see it in your browser). Theoretically, you should click "AGREE" button before clicking "Download".

OH! Makes sense, looking into it, thanks!

Didn't managae to reproduce, can you write the xpath of it?

//span[contains(text(), "AGREE")]

or //button[span[contains(text(), "AGREE")]]

I see only "submit" button in the code: DomNodeList element = page.getElementsByTagName("button"); returns me DomNodeList which contains only "submit" which is also loading... very weird

can you share the result of "page.asXml()" ?

That pop-up that opens, when "Download" is clicked may be already on the page, the click just changes its visibility.

I know, but when I call to element.click(); it didn't change the content of the page. The original xml is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10-icMfxO9hZeu3XeXYJ-nthq5P6s-KJg/view?usp=sharing

you have any idea?

I suggest to try BrowserVersion.CHROME to check the behaviour with different browser, or try to use Selenium instead of HTML Unit.

Selenium isn't possible and BrowserVersion.CHROME didn't change something...

AFAIK the Edge is based on Chromium, just like Chrome. So maybe try Firefox?

It didn't help, thanks anyway!
